# How do I select an element from a list in pandas?

Tags: python, python-3.x, pandas, list, dataframe

So, I created a column that stores a list with multiple strings,

```
import pandas as pd

lists = [['a1','b2'],['a1','b2','c3'],['b2','c3']]
series = pd.Series(lists, index =['XXX', 'YYY', 'ZZZ'])

series

# XXX        [a1, b2]
# YYY    [a1, b2, c3]
# ZZZ        [b2, c3]
```

and I want to check if a letter is part of the string, and them select based on some criteria, like:

```
if 'b' in series['XXX']:
    series['XXX'] = element containing the selected letter
```

Desired result:

```
XXX| b2         
YYY| [a1, b2, c3]         
ZZZ| [b2, c3]
```

Is there any way to do this iterating over all the rows ?

Comment: do you want to select only one element from list ?

Comment: you have standard list so you can use list comprehensions to get new list `series['XXX'] = [x for x in series['XXX'] if 'b' in x]` and evetually you can use `[0]` to get only first element from this list. Problem can be if there is no element with `b` because then `[0]` will gives error.

Answer (score 0):

If I understand correclty, you want to list all elements in your series that contain some letter or string, e.g. 'b'. Although, that would not align with your 'desired outcome'.

However, this would find all elements (and return a Series) containing 'b':

```
string_to_contain = 'b'
series.apply(lambda x: [_ for _ in x if string_to_contain in _])
```